# What is the meaning of "expressive dent"?

Tags: word-meaning

"The toaster oven with the expressive dent".
what is "expressive dent"?

I've found a couple of meanings for expressive and for dent. However I don't know which one adequate here.

Thanks

Comment: Source? This doesn't seem like a regular usage.

Answer (score 1):

The context would likely give clues as to what the author intended. Given what you have written I would interpret it as a unique toaster that has a very telling mark on it from abuse or rough handling. 
Expressive in this case could be interpreted as an euphemism.

Example:

> "Which toaster was it that Sue dropped on the floor?"
>
> I replied, "The toaster
>   oven with the expressive dent."

Comment: To my ears, an "expressive dent" sounds like a humorous phrase you might see in a short story or novel. It's humorous, because normally you think of a sensitive human as being "expressive. And a dent is, well, just a dent. A dent that seems to communicate expressively must be quite a large and complicated dent!

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, it sounds like something from a British comedy, Red Dwarf or similar.

Comment: As you asked, the source is:http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/20/magazine/must-i-pretend-to-like-my-artist-friends-work.html?_r=0    the pharse is located on the last paragraph.